# Angular animations not working for Ionic v1.2.4 (angular v1.4.3)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I recently had to upgrade my Ionic app's version [as I migrated to a different machine], everything worked well and as expected in the app with the exception of animations. All the angular (angular animate) based animations I had no longer work! They were basically CSS transitions applied to the .ng-enter and .ng-leave classes.

I was wondering if this problem has something to do with Ionic now using angular v1.4.3? I [read here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12612) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12267) that it's a bug associated with the 1.4.x versions of angular?

Has this issue been reported before? if so... is there a workaround?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Angular 1.4 brought substantial changes to animation. I suggest a look at the changelog under the Breaking Changes sections: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thank you very much, reviewing.....

Comment: @isherwood Unfortunately, I don't see anything related to how to apply these changes when I'm only applying animations via CSS. (That is, I'm not using the $animate injectable at all), please let me know where can I find this information (if possible). So far, no luck.